# Calculating sample size for stratified sampling

Tags: sampling, sample-size, sample

I have an issue with determining sample sizes for a collection of strata. It regards comparing shares of a binary variable. I'm supposed to find the sample sizes for each strata using both proportional and optimal allocation but I don't have any variability measures. Is there a way to determine sample size without them?

I have prior estimates for the shares of the binary variable for each stratum (p) and the sizes of the strata populations but nothing else.

[image]

Here are the formulas I've been given.

Comment: The stratified allocation formulas for a binary variable do use the proportion (p) in each stratum, not a measure of variability (sigma). Are you sure you're using the correct formula? Can you edit your post to include the formula?

Comment: I've included the formulas I've been given. I need to find nj for each strata but I don't have any variation of n nor any variability measures.